# update statement keeps updating all rows :( , 'OR' relation involved?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, sql-update

Please check why this code keeps updating all the rows in the table

```
    UPDATE FINANCE_ORDERS                                                              
    SET ORDER_STATUS = 'NOT APPROVED EWW'
    WHERE
    ORDER_DATE = '&TIME_1'
    AND
    ((&V5)*(&V6)) < (&V7) 
    OR 
    ((&V5)*(&V6)) - (&V7) < (&V3) 
    OR 
    (&V3) < (&V8) 
    OR
    (&V3) > (&V9)
    /

SQL> /
Enter value for time_1: 12-14-2018 05:53:43
old   4: ORDER_DATE = '&TIME_1'
new   4: ORDER_DATE = '12-14-2018 05:53:43'
Enter value for v5: 15
Enter value for v6: 15000
Enter value for v7: 175000
old   6: ((&V5)*(&V6)) < (&V7)
new   6: ((15)*(15000)) < (175000)
Enter value for v5: 15
Enter value for v6: 15000
Enter value for v7: 175000
Enter value for v3: 1500
old   8: ((&V5)*(&V6)) - (&V7) < (&V3)
new   8: ((15)*(15000)) - (175000) < (1500)
Enter value for v3: 1500
Enter value for v8: 2000
old  10: (&V3) < (&V8)
new  10: (1500) < (2000)
Enter value for v3: 1500
Enter value for v9: 180000
old  12: (&V3) > (&V9)
new  12: (1500) > (180000)

3 rows updated.
```

the code above supposed to update the order status only for those rows with the same date and time (varchar2) such as this (12-14-2018 05:53:43),

the code was working perfectly between the first three conditions until I realize that I made too much of "OR" relations.

Any suggestion how could I fix this code in order to meet all the conditions that I've made? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AND is evaluated before OR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-65B103FE-C00C-46A3-8173-A731DBF62C80), so you have implicit extra parentheses; effectively:

```
UPDATE FINANCE_ORDERS                                                              
SET ORDER_STATUS = 'NOT APPROVED EWW'
WHERE
(
   ORDER_DATE = '&TIME_1'
   AND
   ((&V5)*(&V6)) < (&V7) 
)
OR 
((&V5)*(&V6)) - (&V7) < (&V3) 
OR 
(&V3) < (&V8) 
OR
(&V3) > (&V9)
/
```

If you add additional parentheses yourself you can control the order or evaluation:

```
UPDATE FINANCE_ORDERS                                                              
SET ORDER_STATUS = 'NOT APPROVED EWW'
WHERE
ORDER_DATE = '&TIME_1'
AND
(
  ((&V5)*(&V6)) < (&V7) 
  OR 
  ((&V5)*(&V6)) - (&V7) < (&V3) 
  OR 
  (&V3) < (&V8) 
  OR
  (&V3) > (&V9)
)
/
```

---

Incidentally, assuming that `ORDER_DATE` is a column with data type `DATE` (and it *should* be a date or possibly a timestamp, [not a string](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/see-you-just-cannot-make-this-stuff-up.html)), the `ORDER_DATE = '&TIME_1'` should really have an explicit `TO_DATE()` call with a format mask matching the way you expect the user to enter it, e.g. `ORDER_DATE = TO_DATE('&TIME_1', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`. At the moment you're relying on implicit conversion using whatever the current session's NLS settings happen to be, which may work for you but might not for someone else running the script.

(Also see [`ACCEPT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm) to prompt for the format you expect...)

Comment: exactly @alexpoole, what I did above with the date and time was nothing but (varchar2) I 've made it before as a trigger for the targeted table. the trigger works as to take "SYSDATE"  and to change it TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , so all values inside the finance_orders table (order_date column) are in char as 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'.

Comment: @Abe.Cherry - don't store dates as strings, that's a really bad idea. [Put dates in dates, numbers in numbers, and strings in strings. Never use a datatype to store something other than what it was designed for, and use the most specific type possible.](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/see-you-just-cannot-make-this-stuff-up.html).

Comment: Oh lord, that's a really bad idea X_X. I was about making a big misconception the order_date datatype. how can I thank you ! :)

Comment: It's a surprisingly common thing to see people doing, so I'm glad you caught it early. (Maybe people are being *taught* to do it, like they're still being taight to use the old way to join tables...)